# Ordre des mots avec "rien d'autre" ou "rien ... d'autre"

Tags: ordre-des-mots

J'ai un doute concernant l'ordre des mots dans les constructions avec "rien d'autre" ou "rien ... d'autre". J'ai trouvé quelques examples dans les corrigés d'un livre d'exercices de grammaire, mais je ne comprends pas pourquoi l'ordre des mots doit être comme ça ou s'il y a un ordre alternatif aussi possible.

J'ai cherché dans mon livre de grammaire, mais je n'ai rien trouvé à ce sujet.

Voici les examples que j'ai trouvé dans les corrigés  mentionnés ci-dessus:

- Je ne veux rien voir d'autre.
- Je ne veux rien boire d'autre.
- Je n'ai rien d'autre à faire.

Est-ce qu'on peut dire aussi ?

- Je ne veux rien d'autre à voir.
- Je ne veux rien d'autre à boire.
- Je n'ai rien à faire d'autre.

Answer (score 2):

- Je (ne) veux rien voir d'autre.  ✅
- Je (ne) veux voir rien d'autre.  ✅
- Je (ne) veux rien d'autre à voir.  ❓ (peu ou pas compréhensible)
- **Il (n')y a** rien d'autre à voir ✅
- Je (ne) veux rien boire d'autre. ✅
- Je (ne) veux boire rien d'autre. ✅
- Je (ne) veux rien d'autre à boire. ✅ (relâché)
- Je (n')ai rien d'autre à faire. ✅
- Je (n')ai rien à faire d'autre. ✅ (relâché)